# Creating a responsive Chart with the Grails Google Visualization API Plugin?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails, google-visualization, grails-plugin, responsiveness

I am using the Grails google visualization api plugin with a bootstrap theme and it is working great but I would like to make it responsive somehow.  Is there a simple way to do this through the plugin or some other method?  I pasted a sample chart(complete content of the .gsp) I was working on that displays fine but when I resize the screen it does not work.  Grails 2.5.2   Thanks!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>



</head>
<body>


<gvisualization:columnCoreChart elementId="barchart"
                                hAxis="${[slantedTextAngle: '180', textStyle: [color: 'black', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: 10]]}"
                                bar="${[groupWidth: '50%']}"
                                title="Sales per Month"
                                titleTextStyle="${[color: 'black', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: 14]}"
                                legend="${[position: 'bottom']}"
                                isStacked="${false}"
                                height="${400}"
                                columns="${colData}" data="${chartData}"/>

<div id="barchart"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you'll need to listen for the `resize` event and 'redraw' the chart accordingly -- see `redrawChart` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32523331/5090771) for an example

Comment: Would I need to set the gvisualization tag equal to a function as per the example?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `grails`, this *might* help.

First, give the chart a name, you can use this to access the chart variable in JavaScript.
I think the default is `visualization`.

Add a handler for the `ready` event, and when fired, activate the `resize` listener.

Then you can determine the size the chart should be, and redraw the chart.

But this is where I get lost.
In order to redraw the chart, you need the chart `data` and `options`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script>

    function readyHandler() {
      window.addEventListener('resize', redrawChart, false);
    }

    function redrawChart() {
      var chartHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0) + 'px'
      var chartWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0) + 'px';

      // rebuild options or access hAxis and others from tag
      var options = {
        height: chartHeight,
        width: chartWidth,
        hAxis: {
          slantedTextAngle: '180',
          // rest of options
        }
      };

      // build data
      var arrData = [];
      arrData.push(${colData});    // ??
      arrData.push(${chartData});  // ??

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(arrData);

      // redraw named chart
      gvisBarChart.draw(data, options);
    }

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <gvisualization:columnCoreChart name="gvisBarChart"
                                  elementId="barchart"
                                  hAxis="${[slantedTextAngle: '180', textStyle: [color: 'black', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: 10]]}"
                                  bar="${[groupWidth: '50%']}"
                                  title="Sales per Month"
                                  titleTextStyle="${[color: 'black', fontName: 'Arial', fontSize: 14]}"
                                  legend="${[position: 'bottom']}"
                                  isStacked="${false}"
                                  height="${400}"
                                  ready="readyHandler"
                                  columns="${colData}" data="${chartData}"/>
  <div id="barchart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Back to working on it and trying to see if I can use this to figure it out.  Thanks!