# Resizing generated svg inside jquery resize div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, google-visualization

I'm using a google visualization tool to generate a chart. I want to put this inside a resizable widget-type div.

Here is what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/c9v8b2uy/1/

To resize the div, I'm using the resizable library:

```
$( ".panel" ).resizable({
    alsoResize:".panelBody", 
    alsoResize:"svg" 
});
```

This current resize changes the size of the div, but not the svg inside of it. Therefore, it ends up clipping the chart. My goal is to hopefully resize the chart instead of cutting it's corners.

Also, note that if you manually input a height and width into the panelBody where the chart is generated, the chart size gets adjusted when the page is loaded.

If anyone could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: sounds like you just need to redraw the chart after resize, [here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32523331/5090771) of a general resizing event...