# Issue with google chart is bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization, linechart

When i am trying to add a **google chart** in **bootstrap modal**, it is coming in a **small size**, I have added a **resize function** to redraw it when the **screen size changes**.

Still the chart **onLoad** is **small** but when i resize the window, it occupies the full width.

The issue is **not coming** when i am adding **google chart** in **normal html page**.

[`Normal HTML Page`](http://codepen.io/b0y/pen/QNRZoe) and [`Bootstrap Modal Page`](http://codepen.io/b0y/pen/VaOqzY)

Any type of help is appreciated :)

Comment: set the `width` option in the chart based on the width of the modal...

Comment: @WhiteHat : doing so will not make it responsive :(

Comment: use `resize` event -- see `redrawChart` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32523331/5090771)

Answer (score 0):

Override bootstrap's modal-dialog width setting:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width:100%">
```

... and call your resize function once the modal is open:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    resize();
});
```

Using Bootstrap's [modal events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)